# How to change visibility of widget views(Buttons) programmatically Android

Tags: android

I have two buttons in my android widget and I want to change there visibility at run time i.e. if data is not coming present in local database I want to hide one button.

How can I get the id's of that button and how can I make it visible or invisible.

Please suggest

Comment: using [setVisibility(View.GONE)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) you can hide a view... the button's id is defined in the xml layout

Comment: you can use view.getId() to get the id of that view

Comment: I know setVisibility(View.GONE) hide the button....but in widget we can not set the visibility directly like button.setVisibility(View.GONE)...We have to find the id using remote views.

Answer (score 3):

to hide or show button you can use Remoteview.setViewVisibility(viewid,Remoteview.visibility)

Answer (score 2):

You can not change the visibility like:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>

View button = findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

You have to get the button view like

```
RemoteViews.findViewById(R.id.button, Visibility.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
Button btnFirst=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
btnFirst.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set an id to the buttons you want to change visibility in your xml-layout:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>
```

In your activity call findViewById()-method to locate the button in the ui:

```
View button = findViewById(R.id.button);
```

and finally set visibility:

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: findViewByID is not recognized as existing method what package must be imported before its use?

Comment: `findViewById()` is part of `Activity` class. It can only be used inside Activities and on `View`s. Please clarify your question or create a new one, because with the provided information level it's not possible to give an appropriate answer.

Comment: Your clarification helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```